# What should I put in Stack class destructor if the Stack is implemented using a Vector?

Tags: c++, stack, destructor

```
class Stack{
public:
    Stack(int capacity){
        data.reserve(capacity);
        theSize = 0;
    }
    ~Stack(){
        //What should I put here?
    }
```

Here data is an object of Vector.
I understand that when Stack object is popped from memory, in the end, data's destructor() will initiate and delete the array in data. But do I also have to delete the memory stored by Stack object? How do I do this? Thank you.

Comment: are you just using a `std::vector`?  what type are you storing in the vector?

Comment: If you don't `new` anything, then you don't need to `delete` anything.

Comment: I am using a custom Vector<T> class that uses an array to store the data. I do delete the array in the Vector's destructor.

Comment: Does the custom vector take care of itself?

Comment: Member variables that aren't pointers are destroyed automatically. The destructor of a `vector` will release its own memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends as to what data type your `vector ie data` is storing. If it is something like "`vector<int>`" or something that isn't a pointer then you needn't define the `destructor` as `data` would call the destructor for each of it's elements when it would call `its own destructor`.

However if you are using `vector<int*>` or similar things where the pointers held by `vector (ie data)` are holding variables on the heap (ie they are called using `new` keyword) then you need to explicitly write your `Stack` destructor as :-

```
~Stack()
{
     for (int i=0;i<data.size();++i)
     {
          delete data.at(i);  // or delete data[i]
     }
}
```

The memory stored by the `Stack` object will be due to its data types. If the data types are destroyed then the `Stack` will also be destroyed releasing the memory it was occupying.